# Did the Mayans view the gods as antagonistic to humanity?

Tags: religion, mesoamerica, maya

How did the precolonial Maya view their gods' relationship to mankind, specifically: were they considered **benevolent, neutral, or antagonistic**?  I've seen a number of hints that they may have considered the gods to be angry, interested in wiping out mankind, but I'm afraid I just don't have any good evidence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Mayans viewed their gods as both benevolent, and malevolent. As Sir John Eric Sidney Thompson stated in his book *[Maya History and Religion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0806122471)* the Mayan gods were largely indifferent except for a desire for recognition in the way of frequent offerings. This is confirmed somewhat by the *[Popol Vuh](http://www.utexas.edu/courses/stross/ant322m_files/popolvuh.htm)* which is mostly concerned with how the gods made man.

This [article](https://ojs.lib.byu.edu/spc/index.php/BYUStudies/article/view/6603/6252) argues that the Mayan gods were not akin to most Western conceptions of "gods," and the Mayan gods were just a part of the natural order of the universe, and as such they were not terribly active.

Pre-Colombian sources are somewhat sparse, but there is no glaring evidence to suggest that the Mayan gods were not indifferent gods that could be good and evil.